# Using service/provider with $http and $q in angular config

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want to load some configuration to each controller in app.config section. Each controller needs a different, but non-mutually-exclusive set of data to be loaded. I can't figure out how to achieve this.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){


    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: "partials/pages/dashboard.html",
        controller: "dashboard_controller",
        resolve: { dash_config: 'SomeConfigD'},
    })
    .when('/a', {
        templateUrl: "partials/pages/a.html",
        controller: "a_controller",
        resolve: { dash_config: 'SomeConfigA'},
    })
}])
```

However, I don't want to write seperate factories for `someConfigA` and `someConfigD`, since they share code. I want something like,

```
app.factory('configFactory', function(...){
    var factory = ;

    function get1(){
        // some $http calls here and return a promise
    }

    function get2(){
        // some $http calls here and return a promise
    }

    function get3(){
        // some $http calls here and return a promise
    }
    factory.configA = function(){
        // return a promise to resolve both get1 and get2
    };
    factory.configD = function(){
        // return a promise to resolve both get2 and get3
    };
})
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is `$q.all`, which you can read about [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#methods_all).

I also made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32kSD/) that uses your factory, although I do it in the run method of the module since I didn't want to deal with creating the factory. It looks something like this:

```
f.configA = function(){
    var get12 = $q.all([
        get1().then(thenFn),
        get2().then(thenFn)
    ]).then(function() {
        console.log('both resolved');
    });
    return get12;
};
```

the function in the then is only called when both promises have been resolved (which happen at different times, simulated with `$timeout`

Now the get functions can be reused, Hope this helped!